Does Gemini API Support all file mime types
I am developing a tool that describes what a file is, using Gemini api. However, I had came into this issue of getting an error 400 Unsupported MIME type, when I uploaded a .docx type file. Does the API support all file mime types or just a specific list of file types, since I assumed it would be the same as the gemini website version.
Here's the full terminal output (error):
Uploaded file 'StudentFinalDraft.docx' as: https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/files/4wu650wcz753
Processing...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/haveyoutried/Documents/GeminiSort.py", line 59, in <module>
    keyPair[o] = model.generate_content(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/haveyoutried/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/generativeai/generative_models.py", line 331, in generate_content
    response = self._client.generate_content(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/haveyoutried/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta/services/generative_service/client.py", line 827, in generate_content
    response = rpc(
               ^^^^
  File "/home/haveyoutried/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 131, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/haveyoutried/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 293, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/haveyoutried/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 153, in retry_target
    _retry_error_helper(
  File "/home/haveyoutried/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_base.py", line 212, in _retry_error_helper
    raise final_exc from source_exc
  File "/home/haveyoutried/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 144, in retry_target
    result = target()
             ^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/haveyoutried/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/haveyoutried/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 78, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Unsupported MIME type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

If there is a list as mentioned before, could anyone link me up with it? else, could you explain why is the above shown error has occurred, if .docx file is acceptable?

In the current stage, the file of DOCX (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) can be uploaded to Gemini using Gemini API. But, unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, the DOCX file cannot be used for generating content with Gemini API. I guessed that your error might occur when the content is generated with the DOCX file.
I propose a sample script for testing this situation/
import google.generativeai as genai

api_key = "###" # Please set your API key.
file_name = "sample.docx" # Please set your DOCX file with the path.
name = "sample-name-1"

genai.configure(api_key=api_key)
f = genai.upload_file(path=file_name, name=name, resumable=True)
print(f.uri)

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. By this, you can see that the DOCX file could be correctly uploaded.
https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/files/sample-name-1

Here, content is tried to be generated with this file using the following script.
import google.generativeai as genai

api_key = "###" # Please set your API key.
name = "sample-name-1"
prompt = "Describe this DOCX file."

genai.configure(api_key=api_key)
model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name="models/gemini-1.5-flash-latest")
response = model.generate_content([genai.get_file(name), prompt])
print(response.text)

When this script is run after the DOCX file is uploaded, the following error message is returned.
400 Unsupported MIME type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

From this situation, it is considered that in the current stage, DOCX files cannot be used to generate content.
I believe that this might be resolved in future updates. Because, until recently, PDF data cannot be used to generate content. But, recently, this could be resolved. Ref (Author: me)
If you want to generate content from the DOCX file, as the current workaround, how about converting it to PDF and using it for generating content?

That is a solid workaround, if one might add. But my script is designed to just describe a particular file, no matter the filetype, since it is all within a loop function, I have no control over it. Essentially, what you're saying is that there is still a limited number of file types in which Gemini api can work with?

@UnfreeHeX Thank you for replying. About Essentially, what you're saying is that there is still a limited number of file types in which Gemini api can work with?, I think that the current answer is yes. But, as I have already mentioned in my answer, recently, PDF data got to be able to be used. So, DOCX might be able to also be used in the future update. So, as a current workaround, when the data is converted to PDF and image, all of them can be used with Gemini API. If my answer was not useful, I apologize.
